# Extreme Learning Machine Implementation Error

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to the extreme learning machine (ELM) and trying to implement its code. I am using a sample code from this  [link](https://elm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

```
import elm

# load dataset
data = elm.read("iris.data")

# create a classifier
elmk = elm.ELMKernel()

# search for best parameter for this dataset
# define "kfold" cross-validation method, "accuracy" as a objective function
# to be optimized and perform 10 searching steps.
# best parameters will be saved inside 'elmk' object
elmk.search_param(data, cv="kfold", of="accuracy", eval=10)

# split data in training and testing sets
tr_set, te_set = elm.split_sets(data, training_percent=.8, perm=True)

#train and test
tr_result = elmk.train(tr_set)
te_result = elmk.test(te_set)

print(te_result.get_accuracy)
```

So far, I just ran the below portion of the code and I got an error:

```
import elm

# load dataset
data = elm.read("iris.data")

# create a classifier
elmk = elm.ELMKernel()

# search for best parameter for this dataset
# define "kfold" cross-validation method, "accuracy" as a objective function
# to be optimized and perform 10 searching steps.
# best parameters will be saved inside 'elmk' object
elmk.search_param(data, cv="kfold", of="accuracy", eval=10)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Mahsa/PycharmProjects/test/ELM.py", line 16, in <module>
elmk.search_param(data, cv="kfold", of="accuracy", eval=10)
File "C:\Users\Mahsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\elm\elmk.py", line 489, in search_param
param_kernel=param_ranges[1])
File "C:\Users\Mahsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\optunity\api.py", line 212, in minimize
pmap=pmap)
File "C:\Users\Mahsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\optunity\api.py", line 245, in optimize
solution, report = solver.optimize(f, maximize, pmap=pmap)
File "C:\Users\Mahsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\optunity\solvers\CMAES.py", line 139, in optimize
sigma=self.sigma)
File "C:\Users\Mahsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\deap\cma.py", line 90, in __init__
self.dim = len(self.centroid)
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

I searched a lot to find the solution but it seems many people had this problem and no one offered them any solution. Can anyone help me please?

BTW, I know someone posted the same question on stackoverflow, but since he didn't received any answers I asked this question again.

Comment: The error appears to be saying that you (or elm) are calling `len()` on an object that has no size.

Comment: Someone has reported this bug https://github.com/acba/elm/issues/2 and you can find workarounds. It is most likely Optunity library version incompatibility.